# Idiom request for describing a guy who's crazy but not stupid

Tags: idiom-request

Take Kim Jong-un for example, he's regarded as one of the most dangerous men in the world. However, behind his crazy action we can certainly discern his secret motives for making nuclear threats.

Comment: You could say he's ["crazy like a fox"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241994/where-does-the-phrase-crazy-like-a-fox-originate) = He seems crazy, but he actually has a cunning plan.

Comment: a psychopath: https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/mindmelding/201301/what-is-psychopath-0

Comment: A crazy person is rarely stupid, I think. But many of them are close to "mad" (but "mad" is also another tricky word, e.g., *mad scientists*).

Comment: There's a perception that a *genius* is someone who is crazy or borderline crazy, but very intelligent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- "[There's method in his madness](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/there-s-method-in-his-madness)" - There is often a plan behind a person's apparently inexplicable behavior. Based on a line from Shakespeare 's Hamlet.

> **Polonius**. What is the matter, my lord?
>   **Hamlet**. Between who?
>   **Polonius**. I mean, the matter that you read, my lord.
>   **Hamlet**. Slanders, sir; for the satirical rogue says here that old men have grey beards; that their faces are wrinkled; their eyes purging thick amber and plum-tree gum; and that they have a plentiful lack of wit, together with most weak hams. All which, sir, though I most powerfully and potently believe, yet I hold it not honesty to have it thus set down; for you yourself, sir, should be old as I am if, like a crab, you could go backward.
>   **Polonius**. [aside] Though this be madness, yet there is a method in't. Will you walk out of the air, my lord?